# Likelihood function and plot Pareto distribution for posterior distribution

Tags: r, bayesian, posterior, likelihood

I implemented two ways to obtain the likelihood of a Pareto distribution with unknown $\alpha$, to find the posterior distribution for $\alpha$.

```
set.seed(1)
a0      <- 10
lambda0 <- 30
x       <- rpareto(200, lambda=lambda0, a=a0)


# Likelihood 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
alpha.vals1 <- seq(25, 35, l=200)
lmu1        <- 200*log(alpha.vals1) + 200*alpha.vals1*log(10) - (alpha.vals1 +1)*sum(x)

plot(alpha.vals1, lmu, type='l', xlab=expression(alpha), ylab=expression(l(alpha)), 
     xlim=c(25,35), ylim=c(41627,57239)) 

# Likelihood 2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
loglik <- function(lambda, dados){ 
  sum((dpareto(x, lambda, 10, log=TRUE)))
}
alpha.vals3 <- seq(25, 35, l=200)
lmu3        <- sapply(alpha.vals3, loglik, x)

plot(alpha.vals3, lmu3, type='l', xlab=expression(alpha), ylab=expression(l(alpha)))
```

The first one gives me this plot:

[image]

The second one gives me this:

[image]

Which one is the right likelihood function for the $\alpha$ parameter from a sample with a Pareto distribution?

Comment: Please explain what your two likelihoods consist of... that is, show an algebraic derivation, with your reasoning for each.

Comment: I generated a Pareto sample. I want to see what is the correct plot of the likelihood function of this sample. I implemented two code, which generated 2 differents plot. I ant to know which plot is the correct onde.